# How to convert HTML page in multi page PDF in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following html page

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
    <img src="..."/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make the pdf of this page but every image should be on new page.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over the images using Javascript.
Then for each image store is as an data url with `dom-to-image` [here](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image)

and print each dataUrl  with `pdfmake` [here](http://pdfmake.org/#/)

Answer (score 0):

Use css property 
page-break-before: always;

See example HTML below:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
     .page-heading { page-break-before: always; }
   </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="..."/>    
    <div class="page-heading">
       <img src="..."/>
    </div>
    <div class="page-heading">
       <img src="..."/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```